# How to print the first part of a string split in python

Tags: python, regex

I have data in csv like :

```
 Minneapolis-St. Paul-Bloomington   MN-WI--33460
Charlotte-Gastonia-Rock Hill     NC-SC--16740
Las Vegas-Paradise   NV--29820
New York-White Plains-Wayne  NY-NJ  (MSAD)--35620
```

How can we print only the data before -- in the column?

```
i.e only :
Minneapolis-St. Paul-Bloomington     MN-WI
Charlotte-Gastonia-Rock Hill     NC-SC
Las Vegas-Paradise   NV & so on....
```

Code:

```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   import csv
   import re

   sample="""columnA,ColumnB,columnC
   1,Cleveland-Elyria-Mentor    OH--17460
   2,Dallas-Plano-Irving    TX  (MSAD)--19100
   3,ASJDFJKDJ-kD-JE       WA--21092"""


   open('sample.csv','w').write(sample)
   with open('sample.csv') as sample, open('final_output.csv','w') as output:
   reader = csv.reader(sample)
   writer = csv.writer(output)
   # discard input header
   next(reader)
   # write output header
   writer.writerow(['col1','col2','col3'])
   #process rows
   for row in reader:
        if row:
              for fipsplit in row[1].split('\n'):
               fipsval = re.findall(r'--(\d+)$', fipsplit)
               writer.writerow([fipsplit])
    print open('final_output.csv').read()
```

Comment: Note: group function is not working in python2.7 csv writer

Comment: Why not just do `row[:-7]` if the lines always have 7 characters on the end you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> line = " Minneapolis-St. Paul-Bloomington   MN-WI--33460"
>>> line.split("--")[0]
' Minneapolis-St. Paul-Bloomington   MN-WI'
```

Use `--` as field delimiter and print first element after split the line